# Why does this TableView code work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I made a typo when creating a `UITableViewCell` with this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Creating cell");
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
    return cell;
}
```

The typo is in using `UITableViewStylePlain` instead of `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. The code worked fine, creating new cells. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how those variables are defined.

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
} UITableViewCellStyle;

typedef enum {
   UITableViewStylePlain,
   UITableViewStyleGrouped
} UITableViewStyle;
```

Both `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` and `UITableViewStylePlain` evaluate to 0, so they're interchangeable.

Comment: Bah, you beat me by 13 seconds! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because `UITableViewStylePlain` is declared as:

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewStylePlain, 
    UITableViewStyleGrouped
} UITableViewStyle;
```

And `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` is declared as:

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
} UITableViewCellStyle;
```

In both cases, the value you're talking about is the first in the `enum`, which means they both will compile to `0`.  Hence, they are "interchangeable" (although you definitely should *not* rely on this behavior in production code).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems like an easy mistake to make (and not catch) as there are no immediate consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Both `UITableViewStylePlain` and `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` are constants with an integer value. When you use one of those, you don't actually pass the constant to the method, but the value of the constant.

As described in the other answers, both constants have the same integer value, so `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` will receive a Style ID it can work with, and it doesn't even notice you supplied a constant that doesn't have anything to do with this method.